# Estimate combinations in panel data in r?

Tags: r, combinations, panel

I am trying to maximize the number of data points in a cross sectional panel data. The structure of the matrix that I have is the following with years on the y axis and countries on the x axis:

```
        A     B    C     D 
2000   NA    50    NA    85
2001   110   75    76    86
2002   120   NA    78    87
2003   130   100   80    88
```

Therefore I am trying to find all of the possible combinations of yearly data points to get the most countries per combination. Using the example above I am trying to produce vectors, lists or other sort of object which resembles something like this:

```
2000, 2001, 2002, 2003 = D
2000, 2001, 2003 = D and B
2001, 2002, 2003 = D, A and C
2000, 2001 = D and B
2001, 2002 = D, A and C
2002, 2003 = D, A and C
2000 = D and B
2001 = A, B, C and D
2002 = A, C and D
2003 = A, B, C and D
```

It is sort of an abstract thing to do and I cannot wrap my head around it. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: What is the end goal here? Most R functions will deal with missing data reasonably gracefully

Comment: I am not trying to fill missing data but find all possible country combinations that I could use as a sample pool. I am trying to apply the 'synth' package and need a sample pool of countries. Therefore I just need options of combinations of countries and years of data. I have 144 countries and 47 years of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update

Here is a solution that is a good starting place, but could probably be improved:

```
library(RcppAlgos)
getCombs <- function(myMat, myCap = NULL, minYears = NULL) {

    numRows <- nrow(myMat)
    myColNames <- colnames(myMat)

    if (is.null(minYears))  ## set default
        repZero <- numRows - 1
    else if (minYears >= numRows || minYears < 1)  ## check for extreme cases
        repZero <- numRows - 1
    else
        repZero <- numRows - minYears

    combs <- comboGeneral(v = c(0,1:numRows),
                          m = numRows, freqs = c(repZero, 
                                                 rep(1, numRows)), rowCap = myCap)

    ## I think this part could be improved
    out <- lapply(1:nrow(combs), function(x) {
        myRows <- myMat[combs[x,],]

        if (is.null(nrow(myRows)))
            result <- !is.na(myRows)
        else
            result <- complete.cases(t(myRows))

        myColNames[result]
    })

    myRowNames <- rownames(myMat)
    names(out) <- lapply(1:nrow(combs), function(x) myRowNames[combs[x,combs[x,]>0]])
    out
}
```

Here is the output for the OP's example. (The OP is missing 5 of the outcomes below):

```
testMat <- matrix(c(NA, 50, NA, 85, 110, 75, 76, 86, 120, NA, 78, 87, 130, 100, 80, 88), nrow = 4, byrow = TRUE)
row.names(testMat) <- 2000:2003
colnames(testMat) <- LETTERS[1:4]

getCombs(testMat)
$`2000`
[1] "B" "D"

$`2001`
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D"

$`2002`
[1] "A" "C" "D"

$`2003`
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D"

$`c(2000, 2001)`
[1] "B" "D"

$`c(2000, 2002)`
[1] "D"

$`c(2000, 2003)`
[1] "B" "D"

$`c(2001, 2002)`
[1] "A" "C" "D"

$`c(2001, 2003)`
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D"

$`c(2002, 2003)`
[1] "A" "C" "D"

$`c(2000, 2001, 2002)`
[1] "D"

$`c(2000, 2001, 2003)`
[1] "B" "D"

$`c(2000, 2002, 2003)`
[1] "D"

$`c(2001, 2002, 2003)`
[1] "A" "C" "D"

$`c(2000, 2001, 2002, 2003)`
[1] "D"
```

However, this answer, or any future answer for that matter, won't get you every combination as you have 144 countries and 47 years of data.  That produces a very *very* large number. Every combination of any length up to *n* is equivalent to the [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set). The number of elements in the power set is simply `2^n`. Since we are not counting the equivalent of the empty set, we need to subtract one, thus:

```
library(gmp)
sub.bigz(pow.bigz(2, 47),1)
Big Integer ('bigz') :
[1] 140737488355327
```

Yes, that is over one hundred trillion!!! You will probably need to rethink your approach as there are simply too many outcomes.

All is not lost! You can make use of the `myCap` argument, to limit the number of outcomes, so you can still investigate possible combinations. Observe:

```
set.seed(11111)
biggerTest <- matrix(sample(100, 20*20, replace = TRUE), nrow = 20)

library(countrycode)
colnames(biggerTest) <- LETTERS[1:20]
rownames(biggerTest) <- 1988:2007

## set 10% of values to NA
myNAs <- sample(400, 400 / 10)
biggerTest[myNAs] <- NA

biggerTest[1:6, 1:10]
      A  B  C   D  E  F  G  H  I  J
1988 51 71 79  35 22 33 22 84 68  4
1989 NA 51 73  10 48 NA 62 44 29 60
1990 NA 21 NA  44 91 24 45 62 52 18
1991 91 91 58  79 65 34 36 87 54 32
1992 82  6 74  75 99 NA 20 28 64 30
1993 80 10 43 100 24 22 99 28 22 44

## Getting all 1,048,575 results takes a good bit of time
system.time(allResults <- getCombs(biggerTest))
  user  system elapsed 
49.449   0.726  50.191 

## Using myCap greatly reduces the amount of time
system.time(smallSampTest <- getCombs(biggerTest, myCap = 10000))
  user  system elapsed 
 0.252   0.003   0.257
```

Alternatively, you can use the `minYears` argument to only return results with a minimum number of combinations of years. For example, per the OP's comments to @CPak's answer, if you only want to see results with 15 or more years of combinations, we have:

```
system.time(minYearTest <- getCombs(biggerTest, minYears = 15))
 user  system elapsed 
1.408   0.018   1.428

set.seed(123)
minYearTest[sample(length(minYearTest), 5)]
$`c(1988, 1989, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2001, 2004, 2005, 2007)`
[1] "C" "E" "G" "T"

$`c(1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1993, 1994, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2007)`
[1] "G" "I" "T"

$`c(1988, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2007)`
[1] "D" "G" "K" "M" "T"

$`c(1988, 1990, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 2000, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007)`
[1] "G" "J" "K" "T"

$`c(1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007)`
[1] "E" "G" "T"
```

Or use both arguments together:

```
system.time(bothConstraintsTest <- getCombs(biggerTest, 10000, minYears = 10))
  user  system elapsed 
0.487   0.004   0.494

bothConstraintsTest[1:5]
$`c("1988", "1989", "1990", "1991", "1992", "1993", "1994", "1995", "1996", "1997")`
[1] "E" "G" "H" "J" "M" "R" "T"

$`c("1988", "1989", "1990", "1991", "1992", "1993", "1994", "1995", "1996", "1998")`
[1] "E" "G" "H" "J" "T"

$`c("1988", "1989", "1990", "1991", "1992", "1993", "1994", "1995", "1996", "1999")`
[1] "D" "E" "G" "M" "T"

$`c("1988", "1989", "1990", "1991", "1992", "1993", "1994", "1995", "1996", "2000")`
[1] "D" "G" "J" "M" "R" "T"

$`c("1988", "1989", "1990", "1991", "1992", "1993", "1994", "1995", "1996", "2001")`
[1] "D" "E" "G" "H" "J" "M" "R" "T"
```

## Explanation

The first thing we need to do is to determine every combination of *n* years. This boils down to finding all *n*-tuples of the [multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) `c(rep(0, n-1), 1:n)` or equivalently, the power set of an *n* element set minus the empty set. For example, for the years `2000:2003` (4 year span), the possible combinations are given by:

```
    comboGeneral(v = c(0,1:4), m = 4,
             freqs = c(3, rep(1, 4)))
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]    0    0    0    1
 [2,]    0    0    0    2
 [3,]    0    0    0    3
 [4,]    0    0    0    4
 [5,]    0    0    1    2
 [6,]    0    0    1    3
 [7,]    0    0    1    4
 [8,]    0    0    2    3
 [9,]    0    0    2    4
[10,]    0    0    3    4
[11,]    0    1    2    3
[12,]    0    1    2    4
[13,]    0    1    3    4
[14,]    0    2    3    4
[15,]    1    2    3    4
```

Now, we iterate over each row of our combinations where each row tells us which combination of rows from the original matrix to test for `NAs`. If the particular combination only contains one result, we determine which indices are not `NA`. That is easily carried out by `!is.na(`. If we have more than one row, we employ `complete.cases(t` to obtain the columns that have only numbers (i.e. no occurrences of `NA`).

After this we are just using indexing to obtain names for our outcomes and Voila, we have our desired results.

Comment: That is exactly what I was trying to do. Great package by the way! Thanks so much for the help. I'm just going to cap it and go with the first 'batch' to see if they work, if they dont then i'll just cap it at a higher number.

Comment: Mate, you are the man! Thank you so much. You just saved me a lot of unnecessary coding. Much appreciated, seriously. @JosephWood

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)
```

I first 1) make rownames - the year - a column, 2) convert your data to long format, and 3) discard rows where `is.na(value) == TRUE`

```
df <- data %>%
        mutate(year = rownames(data)) %>%
        gather(countries, value, A:D) %>%
        filter(is.finite(value)) %>%
        arrange(year) %>%
        select(-value)
```

`valid_countries` is a function that filters `df` for years-of-interest (`vec` is each combination of years), then filters for countries that are found in all the years in years-of-interest. It returns a 2-element vector of the `[years-of-interest as a comma-separated string, valid-countries as comma-separated string]`

```
valid_countries <- function(df, vec) {
    ans <- df %>%
            filter(year %in% vec) %>%
            count(countries) %>%
            filter(n == length(vec)) %>%
            pluck("countries")
    c(toString(vec), toString(unique(sort(ans))))
}
```

The following `lapply` will iterate through `1:N` years of the Number of years in your data. It will draw unique combinations of the years, of size `1:N`, then return valid-countries based on the specified conditions. I format the data into an easier to read format with `as.data.frame(t(Reduce(...)))`

```
result <- lapply(
            seq_len(length(unique(df$year))),
            function(i) {
                apply(
                    combn(unique(df$year), i), 
                    2,
                    function(j) { valid_countries(df, as.numeric(j)) }
                )
            }
        )
as.data.frame(t(Reduce("cbind", result)))
```

Result

```
                       V1         V2
1                    2000       B, D
2                    2001 A, B, C, D
3                    2002    A, C, D
4                    2003 A, B, C, D
5              2000, 2001       B, D
6              2000, 2002          D
7              2000, 2003       B, D
8              2001, 2002    A, C, D
9              2001, 2003 A, B, C, D
10             2002, 2003    A, C, D
11       2000, 2001, 2002          D
12       2000, 2001, 2003       B, D
13       2000, 2002, 2003          D
14       2001, 2002, 2003    A, C, D
15 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003          D
```

Data

```
data <- read.table(text="A     B    C     D 
NA    50    NA    85
110   75    76    86
120   NA    78    87
130   100   80    88", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
rownames(data) <- 2000:2003
```

Comment: Really useful, thank you. It worked perfectly, just it takes time to loop through so many data points.

Comment: This is a nice answer of how to use `tidyverse`. However it also a good example of why it is a bad idea to use `data.frames` instead of a `matrix` when you have data of the same type. I tried your solution with an example that had 20 countries and 15 years and it took almost five minutes, whereas mine only took 1/2 of a second. Don't take this the wrong way,.. I only mean to help. See [this post](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-July/282666.html) from the R mailing list.

Comment: If I would like for the loop to work through only combinations of countries with more than 10 or 15 years how can I change that in the code? Thank you.

Comment: @PedroEstebanRodriguez, I think you were directing that question towards me (forgive me if not), but in the future if you want to get somebody's attention, you can use the `@` symbol followed by their user name. To answer your question, you can simply subset your original data by only choosing columns (i.e. countries) that have more than 10 to 15 years of data. You can easily do that with something like this `which(apply(biggerTest, 2, function(x) sum(!is.na(x))) > 10)`.

Comment: Sorry about that, I was actually asking @CPak but thank you for the reply. I am currently importing and subsetting data tables and it becomes time consuming to work with matrices. If you know how to modify CPak code to only get combinations of countries with more than 10 or 15 years that would be great. I get rows with one country and one year which is sort of pointless.

Comment: @PedroEstebanRodriguez, you can easily convert between matrices and data frames with the functions: `data.matrix` & `data.frame`. To address your specific request, simply take the code from my previous comment and apply it to `data` in CPak's answer like so: `newData < -
 data[ , apply(data, 2, function(x) sum(!is.na(x))) > 10]`. I just want to point out that reducing the number of countries will not have a great impact on computation time, as the majority of the work is done in generating the combinations of cases which, as I've stated before, is incredibly inefficient with data frames.

Comment: I am probably being really annoying right now, but I think I am not making myself clear as to what I am trying to do.  I dont mean to simply drop the countries with less than 10 observations but the combinations of countries with less than ten years. So as to avoid, following Cpak example, rows 1,2,3,4,etc in his result data frame and simply stay with the combinations with more than ten years. @JosephWood

Comment: @PedroEstebanRodriguez, you are not being annoying, I just misunderstood.  I'm not sure how to do this with CPak's code, but I do know how to get what you want with my approach above.  For `combs` variable, we can simply adjust the `freqs` argument to obtain the desired results. I will post an updated solution to better explain myself.

Comment: Thank you, I am currently trying to work through it myself but can't figure out how to filter the comboGeneral so that only >10 are estimated. @JosephWood

Comment: With my method, you need to modify `seq_len(length(unique(df$year)))`, which currently iterates from 1 thru `length(unique(df$year))`. Change to `10:length(unique(df$year))` to find combinations of 10 countries or greater.